# Laravel Session make a request without updating sessions expiry

Tags: php, laravel

I'm displaying a front-end countdown of when the user's session will expire, I want to request the time left without updating it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$ttl = Redis::ttl(config('cache.prefix') . ':' . Session::getId());
return response()->json($ttl);
```

Each time this is requested the ttl is reset back to the `session.lifetime` value.

Comment: Which session driver are you using?

Comment: Also, surely you could just have a countdown equal to the length of the session which starts when the request is made?

Comment: I'm using Redis. And yes I could do that but if another tab is open that resets it it won't update.

Comment: You'd need to create a route which doesn't invoke the session middleware and then rather than use `Session::getId()` you'd need to use `session_id()` or failing that, access the cookie directly `cookie(config('session.cookie'))`

Comment: yeah the only problem with that is the session middleware is global, which would mean changing all my routes just for this. I'm thinking extending the session middleware and adding an if on it's `terminate` method is probably the best way to go

Comment: Only global to routes in routes.php. Create the route in Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php or use that file to include a second routes file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by extending the `StartSession` middleware:

```
class StartSession extends \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession
{

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        if (!$request->is('auth/ping')) {
            parent::terminate($request, $response);
        }
    }

}
```

Where `auth/ping` is the route I don't want the session to save on.

I then registered this in the app container as a singleton, so the terminate method resolves to the same instance:

In `AppServiceProvider->register`:

```
$this->app->singleton('App\Http\Middleware\StartSession');
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing mapWebRoutes() method in app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php looks like this.

```
/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

You can simply add something like the following to that method, or you could duplicate the code above which loads routes.php and remove the web middleware.

```
$router->get('session-ttl', function () {
  return response()->json(
    \Redis::ttl(config('cache.prefix') . ':' . cookie(config('session.cookie')));
  );
});
```

Or

```
$router->group([
    'namespace' => $this->namespace
], function ($router) {
    require app_path('Http/routes_wo_web.php');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I hadn't looked at the `RouteServiceProvider`. I noticed the project was originally created with 5.1 then upgraded to 5.2 so it looks a little different. I've gone with extending the `StartSession` middleware's `terminate` method to check if the request matches the path. I think it's the easier solution as I can still use the session within that route to fetch any values if I need to.

Answer (score 0):

The session stuff is handled by the `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession` middleware, which is in the `web` middleware group.

The simplest solution would be to place your route outside the standard `web` middleware group.

If you need any of the other `web` middlewares, you can add them back to the route.

To actually use the session in your route, you have a couple of options:

- you can make a Session middleware that does not terminate the session (extend the existing one, and override the `handle` method to just `return $next($request)`)
- someone here's suggested that as it's a one off route, you could just start the session manually wherever you're handling your route (nick the code from the existing middleware - it's only a few lines).

I think the recommended solution would be to do it in a middleware, though.

Comment: Thanks, my project was created with Laravel 5.1 and upgraded to 5.2, so it was in the global middleware rather than the `web` group. See my answer - I went with extended the current `StartSession` middleware and changed the `terminate` method.